# SSL with Google App Engine custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps, google-cloud-platform

Does anyone know if it is going to be possible anytime soon to setup SSL for a custom domain without a Google App account directly from the Google cloud developers console? Signing up for yet another Google account is bordering on making me insane.

I have setup a custom domain via the Google cloud developers console for my app project, and this is serving as a naked url...no problem.

Then I tried to setup a Google App account with an existing account linked to my Google App Engine project as an owner, but it didn't like it. So I setup a new one (deleted now) and re-verified the custom domain, which then stopped the serving of the custom domain. I then deleted the Google App account and it started serving the custom domain again. I have no idea why, what or how...

I have purchased an SSL certificate from Comodo, not yet activated, and all I want to do is set it up without giving myself an emotional hernia, I get enough of those from coding! And, yes, read the docs, but you know, they suck! A step by step idiots example would be great!

Does anyone have a guide other than a google doc on how to setup SSL for a custom domain including activating the SSL cert etc. etc.

Thanks one and all

Answer (score 4):

See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=777

> We have added support for custom domains for App Engine from the
>   Google Developers Console, meaning you can now associate a custom
>   domain without first associating that domain with Google Apps.
>
> To access the feature, visit https://console.developers.google.com/
>   and you will find the option to add a custom domain under App Engine >
>   Settings.
>
> NOTE: Currently we do not support SSL on custom domains created
>   through this method (although we expect to rectify this in a future
>   release). In the meantime, we continue to support SSL (via VIP or SNI)
>   for custom domains that are created through Google Apps, and we
>   continue to provide free HTTPS for all *.appspot.com domains.

Comment: Koma, I know that already, paragraph 2 of my question. The issue is why one needs to have yet another account with Google, which not only requires a totally different set of credentials than those used on my general Google accounts, which, I use for my`Google app engine account, developers console analytics etc. etc.

Comment: You have to pay for the SSL usage as it is and that's ok, but then paying for paying for it, if you see my point is a little overboard. Not only that, but when I setup the Google App account (now deleted), and had to verify the custom domain again, it stopped the custom domain from serving. So what is with this complicated approach Google. Surely, it would be a zillion times easier to just add custom domains and SSL for them independantly of having a Google App account. Rant over!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I have discovered that Google are moving the SSL setup to their developers cloud console at the end of August 2015. So I shall wait until then to see what that process is like and then decide to go with it or perhaps use Cloudflare or some other alternative if there is one.

Comment: They kept on delaying for a about 3 - 4 months now, and now 1st of September, I been waiting to cancel my google apps account as its just a waste as I only need email, and playing 5$ a month is way to much for my simple requirements.